# Vuex best practices for working with additional classes: import into view or only in the Store?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

I am building an application and am not sure how to phrase this question in a way that would help me find anything on Google.

My question is: *When using a Vuex store along with some additional classes, is it best practice for the view components to access those classes directly or should they only be accessed through the store?*

More detail: Currently, my project has a Vuex store with modules (**userModule** manages the current logged-in user, **uiModule** manages certain user-interface elements' visibility and content, etc).

I also have some services. **AuthService** contains the methods for communicating with Firebase's Auth, **DatabaseService** contains Firestore read/write methods.

I import the services into the Vuex store modules that require them, and access them as needed through the Store. Reading over my code, in some cases I have accessed the services directly from the view - for instance, **Login.vue** imports **AuthService** and accesses it directly. like so:

```
import authService from '../services/auth.service';

export default {
...
  computed() {
     authService() { return authService }
  }
...
}
```

```html
<button>{{authService.auth.currentUser() ? 'log out' : 'log in'}}</button>
```

I think overall it would be better to use the Store, as it would reduce the number of times I import the same object - though I'm not sure how much of a concern it is to import the same object multiple times. Confirmation and discussion are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no penalty for importing the same module multiple times throughout your project, the top-level code in that module will only be executed once.

I don't think there's a right or wrong answer to your question (it may get closed for being "opinion-based").

- Every time you import a module, it becomes a direct dependency of the importing module. This may make unit testing more difficult – how can you cleanly mock the imported module? (Certainly there are ways to do this, I'm just playing devil's advocate.)
- When you expose the service class directly on the component instance like you have, then the service class becomes dependent on Vue now because the data properties it exposes need to be reactive for it to be used within the template like that. Vue will make all the properties on the class reactive now. The class implementation also needs to be aware that this will happen and it must comply with Vue's reactivity limitations when it mutates its own data.
- For something simple like getting the current user, to me that seems more appropriate to store in Vuex instead of requiring every module import `auth.service`.
- Try to maintain only a single "source of truth", don't share the ownership of data around because it becomes difficult to maintain.